# Homeomorphism between spiral and positive real axis

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

I have given the following two subsets of $\mathbb{R^2}$:
$$ M = \lbrace{(t,0) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \rbrace | t >0 \rbrace},~~ N = \lbrace{ ( t \cos(1/t),t \sin(1/t)) \in \mathbb{R}^2 | t > 0\rbrace}.$$
The exercise asks me to show that there is a homeomorphism $\psi \colon \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ that satisfies $\psi(M) = N$.
My approach was to identify $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the complex plane $\mathbb{C}$ using the map $(x,y) \mapsto z = x+ iy$, then the map $z \mapsto w = z \exp(i/z)$ and finally map back to $\mathbb{R}^2$ with $w \mapsto (\text{Re}(w),\text{Im}(w))$. This however does not lead to a continuous function on $\mathbb{R}^2$ and I don't see what function I could take in stead of $ z \exp(i/z)$ to satisfy $\psi(M) = N$. I would be thankful for any hints as to how I can find this homeomorphism.

Comment: [Show that, the spiral and the half straight line in $\Bbb{R}^2$ are homeomorphic.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3706575/show-that-the-spiral-and-the-half-straight-line-in-bbbr2-are-homeomorphic/3706651#3706651) might be helpful

Comment: Thanks! I however need a homeomorphism between R^2 and R^2 not just the real line and the spiral

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Identifying $\mathbb R^2$ with $\mathbb C$, define $$f(z)=ze^{-i/|z|}$$
In polar cohordinates this is $f(\rho,\theta)=(\rho,\theta-1/\rho)$. Then check that $f$ extends contintuously in $z=0$ by $f(0)=0$ and  that the result is indeed a homeo.

Your spiral $N$ in polar cohordinate is $\{(\rho,1/\rho)|\rho>0\}$, so $f(N)$ becomes $\{(\rho,0)|\rho>0\}=M$.

Comment: Thank you! That clears it up. I guess I have to use $f^{-1}$ though to get $\psi(M) = N$.